# OAuth2 (NOT SDK) + Facebook - Not showing the permissions to user

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I tried following urls and all work:

- https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s&display=popup&scope=%s
- https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s&scope=%s
- https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/oauth?client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s&scope=%s

All 3 work, the first two ones return simple token results and the last one a json result with the token in it. I just use a webview and let the user login to facebook via the webview. All works fine and my app get's access to all data in the requested scopes.

**Problem**

The required scopes (permissions) are not shown to the user, the user just sees a login window and if he logs in in my app, my app get's a valid token. That's it. This way facebook does not approve my app. I think, the correct login flow should be handled by facebook and if I call the oauth login urls facebook should redirect correctly and only return the token after they have asked the user if he wants to allow the required permissions.

*So what am I doing wrong? Why are the permissions are not shown to the user before facebook returns the valid token?*

**EDIT:**

**Requirements:** NO SDK, because I want to use a common OAuth2 flow for many social networks and cloud services, so I don't want to add the sdk for every single service...

**Code**

I just call the above urls and follow the redirects until I get a correct answer with an access token, that's it.

Comment: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) check this link and also post your code

Comment: the link shows the progress with the SDK, I don't want to use the sdk, I will use many sources in my app so I want to use a common sdk independent way... That's why I want to use a normal OAuth2 approach. This link does fit my needs better: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow. Still, I can't get my app to show the permission information to the user...

Comment: Did you solved this issue ? I got the same for a web app as of today.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) requires scopes be separated by spaces, but Facebook's implementation requires scopes be separated by commas. This violation may be the root cause.

Comment: Sadly that's not the cause, I'm using following scope: `user_photos,user_videos`. If I remember correctly, facebook api will return an error if the scope is space separated...

Comment: In RFC 6749, `response_type` is a required parameter. Adding the parameter may change the response.

Comment: How about adding `auth_type=rerequest`? Declined permissions are not re-asked unless you add this parameter explicitly, the Facebook document says.

Comment: facebook is not complaining about the extra parameter, but still it's not showing a confirmation dialog...